# Q:can the throwable creation in AbstractWire.startUse and endUse be optional

Tags: garbage, chronicle

I'm using chronicle-network to build an event replication service cross hosts, and during a simple jmc profiling I find that in AbstractWire startUse and endUse method creates Throwable object each time, and those methods are extensively used in each network handler wire process, which could be consider as a few "garbage".

I guess this is used for tracing purpose, given it could rely on the thread reference to guarantee single thread operation, I'm ask if the object creation could be optional by configuration?
Or there are other reason to creating this object, could you share some of your thoughts or advices.

thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public boolean startUse() {
    Throwable usedHere = this.usedHere;
    Thread usedBy = this.usedBy;
    if (usedBy != Thread.currentThread() && usedBy != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Used by " + usedBy + " while trying to use it in " + Thread.currentThread(), usedHere);
    }
    this.usedBy = Thread.currentThread();
    this.usedHere = new Throwable(); // <-- create throwable here
    usedCount++;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean endUse() {
    if (usedBy != Thread.currentThread()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Used by " + usedHere, usedHere);
    }
    if (--usedCount <= 0) {
        usedBy = null;
        usedHere = null;
        usedCount = 0;
        lastEnded = new Throwable(); // <-- create throwable here as well
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, turns out that all startUse and endUse invocation are guarded by JVM assert statement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are safety checks that should be enabled during the development/QA phase. When running in production, the intention is that the jvm is started with the following argument:

```
-da:net.openhft
```

in order to disable these safety checks.